# SQL Sort Order with Null values last

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following test-code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Foo (Foo int)

INSERT INTO #Foo SELECT 4
INSERT INTO #Foo SELECT NULL
INSERT INTO #Foo SELECT 2
INSERT INTO #Foo SELECT 5
INSERT INTO #Foo SELECT 1

SELECT * FROM #Foo
 ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Foo IS NULL THEN Foo DESC ELSE Foo END

DROP TABLE #Foo
```

I'm trying to produce the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
NULL
```

"If null then put it last"

How is that done using Sql 2005

/M

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One way is to sort it like this:

```
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN Foo IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), Foo
```

Or: First sort by null, then sort by the Foo contents.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do

```
SELECT * FROM #Foo ORDER BY COALESCE(Foo, 2147483647)
```

which will replace NULL with the largest possible int for the purposes of sorting only (so leaving the retured values alone) and so shunt it to the back of any order.

Comment: Er, downvote why chaps? Check this if you want, it does exactly what the poster asked and is just as efficient as the other posted solution for less code.

Comment: Any other issues aside, this has the downsides of knowing the "maximum value" (and ensuring that it isn't really used for something else).