# Null value in order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird scenario, in which I need to keep all the rows at top in which X column has  NULL value else sort by Y column. Can you help me in writing query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case Order by using Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498240/case-order-by-using-null)

Answer (score 5):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN X IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Y
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement in `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN X IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this will work with any sql platform -- for a specific platform there might be a better way to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 1 AS orderC, *
  FROM tableName
  WHERE Xcolumn is null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS orderC, *
  FROM tableName
  WHERE Xcolumn is not null
)
ORDER BY orderC ASC, columnY
```

Note, if you don't want orderC to be in the output, just specify all the other columns in the outer select.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what I learned before using:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(Xcolumn, NULL) DESC, Ycolumn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY X ,Y
```

Comment: @Hogan yes you are right , I hope it will show desired result , because `NULL` values come first in `Order By` clause , am i right ?

Comment: -That depends on the platform -- Oracle for instance has `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST` options.  Which is why I said mine was platform agnostic.  If you know the platform there is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: If the user is asking then I think they are you SQL Server which puts them last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like below:

```
  SELECT * FROM Emp WHERE empId= 6 AND DELETED = 0
    ORDER BY  CASE WHEN DOB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

, CREATETIMESTAMP.
```

for more details you can see [here](http://bel-technology.blogspot.in/2013_09_01_archive.html)